# HTTPS Events from datastream

Tags: https, data-stream

How do I get the HTTPS event from raw data?

Comment: Huh? What events? Using what API? For what purpose?

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to decrypt captured HTTPS network packets after the fact, that is not normally possible. You need *at least* the HTTPS session keys, which can only be retrieved by modifying the browser - but if you have that kind of access to the browser, you can intercept the unencrypted data anyway.

Things are [easier](http://wirewatcher.wordpress.com/2010/07/20/decrypting-ssl-traffic-with-wireshark-and-ways-to-prevent-it/) if you have the private key of the HTTPS server, although there are encryption algorithms that use [Diffie-Hellman key exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) to offer [perfect forward secrecy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_forward_secrecy), thus making the decryption of captured data impossible.

See also [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) Wikipedia article, if you would like more information on the TLS/SSL protocol that is used in HTTPS.

If you are only interested in monitoring your own browser, e.g. for debugging, you might be able to use a plugin, such as [LiveHTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) for [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/new/), that will tap into the browser internals to show you what is being transmitted and received via an encrypted connection.